# Proportions of an isosceles triangle whose orthocentre lies on the incircle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle for which $AB = AC$. Suppose the orthocentre of the triangle lies **on** the in-circle. Find the ratio $\frac{AB}{BC}$.

This problem is taken from the $31$st **Indian National Mathematical Olympiad.**
I am looking for all possible solutions to this problem( to better understand $- $ the strategies to solve Geometry problems)

**Note:-** I don't know much Co-ordinate Geometry. So, please restrict your answers to the scope of Euclidean Geometry.

Comment: Euclidean geometry and Coordinate geometry are the same thing, in many axiomatizations.

Comment: If you're looking to understand strategies to solve geometry problems, why would you ask that we only use methods you already understand?

Comment: Are they. I've heard that Euclidean Geometry is the type Greeks did Geometry. While, Co-ordinate Geometry is more about the Co-ordinates and the algebra of things.

Comment: @Semiclassical. Because I am an olympiad aspirant and we have to restrict from the use of Co-ordinate Geometry.

Comment: @Lucifer-: I have never heard that coordinate geometry is not allowed as an "olympic tool". On the contrary, it is often taught as a technique to crack geometry problems, when an elegant and elementary approach seems hard to find.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. In India, for the first two stages, Euclidean Geometry is more focused on. For International And National Level(IMOTC), Co-ordinate is allowed.

Comment: By Euler's theorem, if we put the origin at the circumcenter $O$ we have $H=A+B+C$. 
On the other hand, $I=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}$, so $H$ lies on the incircle iff
$$ \left\|(b+c)A+(a+c)B+(a+b)C\right\|=r(a+b+c)=2\Delta $$
or
$$ R^2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)^2 + 2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)\langle B,C\rangle =4\Delta^2$$
or
$$ 4R^2\left(a+b+c\right)^2 - \sum_{cyc}a^2(a+b)(a+c) = 4\Delta^2 $$
or
$$ (4R^2-r^2)(a+b+c) = (a^3+b^3+c^3+abc). $$

Comment: That is a solution to a more general question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the triangle is isosceles, the orthocentre lies on the perpendicular $AD$ from $A$ on to $BC$. Let it cut the incircle at $H$.

Let $D$ be the mid-point of $BC$. Extend $AD$ to meet the circumcircle in $L$. Then we know that $HD=DL$. But, we have, $HD=2r$ where $r$ is the inradius of triangle $ABC$. Thus, $DL=2r$. Therefore, $IL=ID+DL=r+2r=3r$. We also know that $LB = LI$. Therefore $LB = 3r$. This gives $$\frac{BL}{LD} = \frac{3r}{2r} = \frac{3}{2}$$
   But triangle $BLD$ is similar to triangle $ABD$. So
Finally, we get, $$\frac{AB}{BD} = \frac{BL}{LD} = \frac{3}{2}$$ Hence, $$\frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{AB}{2BD} = \frac{3}{4}$$ Hope it helps.